# Using `\mathcal` With and Without Package

Tags: fonts, packages, amsmath, mathcal

This is going to seem like a simple question. However I hope it gets answered nonetheless.

So, I want to be able to use the default `\mathcal` font setting AND the `eucal`-package font setting as well. How do I use both in a single document?

Thank you. If elaboration is needed, please let me know (even though I believe this question is very straight forward).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method 1: use `\CMcal` for the default `\mathcal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eucal}

\begin{document}
  \[\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
  \[\CMcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: method 1]

Method 2: use `\mathscr` for the alternative script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\begin{document}
  \[\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
  \[\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: method 2]