# What mathmode font is this character?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

The character is the `R` in this picture:

[image]

I was thinking mathcal or fraktur, but it doesn't seem to be either of them. I tried the Detexify tool and What The Font, but couldn't find anything suitable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: @Werner It's about the font I think and not about the symbol/character.

Comment: I assume that you are looking for **\mathcal** (as you mentioned in your question). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280701for example.

Comment: Thanks, I had also thought it was mathcal, but it looks a bit different than that

Comment: It's a calligraphic/script R; the exact shape is not semantically important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly but almost

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\bm{\mathcal{R}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]